# ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using the Percona mysql client to connect to a database, `mysql  Ver 8.0.15-5 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)`

```
mysql> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_connection';
Variable_name   Value
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
mysql> call unit_create_with_dummy_users;
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
mysql>
```

Unlike other error messages like [Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027987/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8mb4-general-ci) I believe all the tables are of the same collation, but my **collation_connection** isn't? Or perhaps I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for that Stored Procedure were established when the proc was created.  See `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE unit_create_with_dummy_users`.
- The charset and collation of the *connection* is the other factor.  It is apparently different.
- The charset and collation of the *table* is a third factor.

Without seeing the actual statement, *inside the proc*, that caused the "illegal mix", we cannot advise you on the simplest way to avoid the problem.