# Resolving 'Illegal-mix-of-collations' MYSQL error in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, collation

I am connecting to a mysql database from node using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and have been experiencing intermittent illegal-mix-of-collations errors - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027987/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8mb4-general-ci). The collation of the database is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

I have tried adding `charset: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'` to my connection config:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'test',
    charset: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
});
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/341333/2627160) charset and collation are not interchangeable, which would suggest 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' is an invalid charset value, but it seems to have fixed the problem and I'd prefer a solution that works at connection level, as it's cleaner that setting collation on individual columns in my queries (as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027987/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8mb4-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8mb4-general-ci)).

Is this a valid approach to resolving these issues? If not, is there a better solution?

The charset of the database is `utf8mb4`.

Comment: If the conflict is between two columns in your tables, no connection 'fix' exists. The connection property can only impact literal values in your queries. For example in `table.foo = 'bar'` the connection property explicitly states the collation to be used for `'bar'`, but has no impact on the tables and can not 'fix' conflicts such as `table1.foo = table2.bar`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @MatBailie - I've checked the tables and the collations are consistent, so I'd guess it is a literal value where the issue is arising? E.g. if I set the queried value as a variable (because it's used several times in the query) and then compare this with a column, could this throw an 'Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT)' error?

Answer (score 0):

> charset: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

That's a collation.  The "charset" is `utf8mb4`.

The "connection" is stating what encoding (charset) is in use in the *client*.  MySQL will convert between charsets if necessary, but it is based on the connection charset and the column charset.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. It's just a naming issue. `mysql2` understands both a *charset* and a *collation* for the `charset` option. You can see the comment in the source code here - https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/a7aecaa9090b5430b052cf2f8cb38a594e32b3a7/typings/mysql/lib/Connection.d.ts#L124

> The charset for the connection. This is called 'collation' in the
> SQL-level of MySQL (like utf8_general_ci). If a SQL-level charset is
> specified (like utf8mb4) then the default collation for that charset
> is used. (Default: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI')